# I want to scroll up this modal pop up page to click this submit button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**I click this submit button it scrolls up to the back of the page. but I want to scroll up the modal page.**

**The image is attached below**
[image]

**I wrote a function like this**

```
 const handleScrollTop = () => {
    window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: "smooth" });
  };
```

**In the button I set the onClick event**

```
<button
     className="btn btn-primary col-md-4"
     type="submit"
     onClick={handleScrollTop}
>
Submit
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

While using [scrollTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo) we can use the `element` we wanted to scroll than `window` itself ...

I'm using native `dialog` but the idea should be same.

Please refer the `submitHandler` on how I am doing the `scrollTo` ...

```js
const {useRef} = React;

const App = () => {
  const dialogRef = useRef(null);

  const openDialog = () => {
    dialogRef.current.showModal();
  };
  
  const submitHandler = () => {
    // like so ... instead of window
    dialogRef.current.scrollTo({
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      behavior: "smooth",
    });
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <dialog id="favDialog" ref={dialogRef}>
        <form>
          <p>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
            industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
            since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
            scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only
            five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
            remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
            the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and
            more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
            including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of
            the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
            industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
            printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
            book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
            electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was
            popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets
            containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
            publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
            Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and
            typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard
            dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley
            of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived
            not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
            typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in
            the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum
            passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
            Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is
            simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem
            Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the
            1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it
            to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
            but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially
            unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of
            Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
            with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including
            versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
            printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
            standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took
            a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
            survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
            typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in
            the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum
            passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
            Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
          </p>
          <div>
            <button type="button" id="confirmBtn" onClick={submitHandler}>
              Confirm
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </dialog>
      <p>
        <button id="updateDetails" onClick={openDialog}>
          Update details
        </button>
      </p>
      <output></output>
    </div>
  );
};


ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <App/>
);
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

dialog {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```